# Three-dimensional analog to a discrete two-dimensional spiral

Tags: graph-theory, 3d, path-connected, hamiltonian-path

Starting at some point in an infinite 2D grid, there is a simple and intuitive path to visit every other point exactly once using only unit-length movements in the directions of the basis vectors. It's a discrete spiral that looks like this:

```
.----.----.----.----.
|                   |
.    .----.----.    .
|    |         |    |
.    .    .----.    .
|    |              |
.    .----.----.----.
|
.----.----.----.----.----.
```

The infinite continuation of this pattern is guaranteed to visit all points $(x,y)$ $\vert$ $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$. Obviously, such a pattern cannot exist in 1D, since movement in one direction leaves all points in the opposite direction inaccessible without visiting some point twice.

I want to know if there is a proof for or against the existence of such a path in 3D. I naively tried to trace a path around a 3x3 cube but was unsuccessful. I tried again with a 2x2 cube and the 4x4 cube enveloping it, but this failed as well. After a few other failed leads, I gave up on trying to trace the path out by hand. I was, however, able to find a path under such constraints in 4D.

I am not looking for a Hilbert curve or any other space-filling curve that maps the unit line segment to the unit cube. I'm specifically looking for a path that, starting at some point and moving only one unit at a time along the x, y, or z axis, is guaranteed to visit every point $(x, y, z)$ in an infinite 3D grid exactly once.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Under what conditions does the n-dimensional, infinite, unit-square-grid graph contain a Hamiltonian ray?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339172/under-what-conditions-does-the-n-dimensional-infinite-unit-square-grid-graph-c)

Comment: @GerryMyerson The answer to that question would be very useful to me, but it seems too good to be true. I'd like to see an animation or some sort of graphical representation of the accepted answer, because if it's true, it's exactly the information I need. I just can't picture it as it's written. I'll try to write up a little turtle program to see it in action.