# Tiling a 7×7 rectangle with trominoes

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

We are given a $7 \times 7$ array. We want to remove a $1 \times 1$ square, such that the remaining shape can be covered with $1 \times 3$ triomino.

What are the possible positions of the eliminated square?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Could you show us what you've tried?

Comment: A natural think for problems like this is to color the board with three colors such that each tromino covers one square of each color.  Can you find such a coloring?  What does that tell you?

Comment: [I discussed the 8×8 version of this problem here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176887/when-chessboards-meet-dominoes/176939#176939).

Comment: The very same question has been asked today 2 hours ago by the same @knm and has had an answer there by Mark Fischler:(https://www.queryxchange.com/q/21_2311209/tiling-a-7-215-7-rectangle-with-trominoes/)

Answer (score 6):

You can color the array as
$$
\pmatrix{
0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
}
$$
and since there are $17$ zeros and $16$ of each other number, the missing square has to be a $0$.

But you can also color it as
$$
\pmatrix{
0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
}
$$
so the missing quare has to be $0$ in both colorings, that is, it has to be a corner or a midpoint of a side, or the center point.

It is easy to see how to do the tiling in each of these cases:

- If a corner is missing, say the upper left corner, then place to triminoes horizontally covering the top, and the rest vertically, two in each column.
- If a midpoint of a side is missing, do the same, only now the two horizontal triminoes are separated by the missing space.
- if the center square is missing, then place two triminoes horizontally across the center row, separated by the center space.  You are left ith two 3x7 horizontal bands, which can be tiled vertically.

Comment: Well, isn't this *special*... How nice of you to provide the asker, who has shown no effort, nor has replied to or acknowledged earlier comments, with an answer on a silver platter.  And in so doing, you also spread the word that anyone can ask anything here on mse, whether they've tried or not, whenever they want a quick and complete full answer/solution  that they can turn in as their own!

Comment: Perfect solution!

Answer (score 1):

Tip: Work out what blocks can be placed in the grid: $1 \times 3, 4 \times 3, 7 \times 3, 5  \times 3, 6/times 3 $ etc.

Tip 2: Use Trial and error:

Tip 2.1: Eliminate parts of the grid with $7 \times x$ blocks to make the grid smaller to work with. This methods workings can be easily proved

Tip 2.1.1 : Don't crop smaller than a $4 \times 4$ grid

Tip X:

> If you haven't noticed already, symmetries and rotations are equivalent to each other.

The answer I got was $9$. Since I believe that you haven't attempted this yourself, I will leave the proof to you, using the tips above...

Comment: Based on the other answer it looks like there are many more than $9$ possibilities

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee  "symmetries and rotations are equivalent to each other."  So, think again.