# Tiling a 7x9 rectangle with 2x2 squares and L-shaped trominos

Tags: combinatorial-geometry, rectangles, tiling

It's possible to cover a 7x9 rectangle using **0** 2x2 squares and **21** L-shaped trominos, for example:

```
abbcddeef
aabccdeff
gghiijjkk
glhhimjnk
lloppmmnn
qoorpstuu
qqrrssttu
```

It's also possible to cover it with **3** 2x2 squares and **17** L-shaped trominos, for example:

```
aabbccdee
fagbcddee
ffgghhijj
kkllhhiij
kklmmnnoo
ppqrmsnot
pqqrrsstt
```

However, it is **not** possible to use **more than 3** 2x2 squares, that is, the remaining four combinations don't work:

- **6** 2x2 squares and **13** L-shaped trominos
- **9** 2x2 squares and **9** L-shaped trominos
- **12** 2x2 squares and **5** L-shaped trominos
- **15** 2x2 squares and **1** L-shaped tromino

...at least this what I got using brute force (a simple C program based on backtracking). I tried to give a mathematical proof for this, but I couldn't.

Please help me find a proof which explains **why** more than 3 2x2 squares cannot be used. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown The question is, how can this claim be proved?

Comment: What's "the normal way" to prove this that you refer to?

Comment: @MichaelLugo I would like to find a mathematical proof, because I don't like computer based proofs. My C code tried every possible way to find a tiling with a given number of 2x2 squares and L-trominos, but it does not tell anything about **why** one cannot use more than 3 2x2 squares.

Comment: Tile homology groups can be useful for these types of questions. http://www.cflmath.com/Research/Tilehomotopy/tilehomotopy.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2311228/80827) (to a different tiling problem) gave me the idea to use more than 2 colors to color the 7x9 rectangle (I have already tried the chessboard coloring without any success).

I devised a coloring scheme with which every 2x2 square always covers the same number of fields for each color, independently of its position. This can be achieved using 3 colors (say, `a`, `b` and `c`):

```
ababababa
bcbcbcbcb
ababababa
bcbcbcbcb
ababababa
bcbcbcbcb
ababababa
```

The number of fields per color: $a = 20, b = 31, c = 12$.

Every 2x2 square covers 1 `a`-, 2 `b`- and 1 `c`-fields. Let $S$ denote the total number of 2x2 squares.

There are 3 groups of L-shaped trominos:

- Group-1 trominos cover 1 `a`-, 1 `b`- and 1 `c`-fields.
- Group-2 trominos cover 1 `a`-, 2 `b`- and 0 `c`-fields.
- Group-3 trominos cover 0 `a`-, 2 `b`- and 1 `c`-fields.

Let $L$, $L_1$, $L_2$ and $L_3$ denote the total number of L-trominos, and the number of trominos in each group, respectively. The following equations hold:

\begin{align}
L_1 + L_2 & = a - S \\
L_1 + 2L_2 + 2L_3 & = b - 2S \\
L_1 + L_3 & = c - S
\end{align}

(*Note:* The summation of these equations gives

\begin{align}
3(L_1 + L_2 + L_3) & = a + b + c - 4S \\
3L + 4S & = a + b + c \\
3L + 4S & = 63 \; (= 7 \cdot 9)
\end{align}

as expected.)

The solution for the above system of equations:

\begin{align}
L_1 & = \frac{2a - b + 2c - 2S}{3} = 11 - \frac{2S}{3} \\
L_2 & = \frac{a + b - 2c - S}{3} = 9 - \frac{S}{3} \\
L_3 & = \frac{-2a + b + c - S}{3} = 1 - \frac{S}{3}
\end{align}

It's already mentioned in the question that the only possible values for $S$ are 0, 3, 6, 9, 12 and 15. Substituting these values into the expressions for $L_1$, $L_2$ and $L_3$ shows that while both $L_1$ and $L_2$ are positive for all $S$ values, $L_3$ becomes negative for $S > 3$, which means that our tiling problem  cannot be solved using more than 3 2x2 squares.

Comment: The calculations are even simpler if 4 colors are used: `abab...` on the 1st line, `cdcd...` on the 2nd line, etc. In this case, there are 4 tromino groups, and similarly to the 3-color case, the size of one group becomes negative for $S > 3$.